# File.length() in Java returns incorrect length

Tags: java, file, unix

I have a binary file. While I run ls -l, it has 12 bytes. However, When I try to find the File's length with File.length, the result is only 9. This is the hex representation of my file (got from `xxd -p`):

```
2090887fffd0ffff437ffd0c
```

Here is the code

```
currentBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, bufferOffset, Math.min(1024, fileLength - bytesRead));
```

Here is the input file

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/y508vsy8m2e8s9n/input.txt?dl=0

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Comment: What if you use readAttributes instead?  That will return all the file's metadata so you can check that the file Java is reading really is the one you think it is.

Comment: i would be nice to know what system you are using, and provide code with file length test.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Length is correct. Show code please with which you get the wrong result.

Comment: Unless you are certain the files length is actually 12 your question's subject should really be, "File.length() inconsistent with ls -l and xxd -p".  A `unix` tag would also help bring in the right people.

Comment: Can you supply code that would reproduce the problem on someone elses system?  Either java code or script that would produce the inconsistently sized file combined with tests that show the different sizes.

Comment: readAttributes does solve the problem. Thanks GordonM

Answer (score 0):

From Javadoc:

> Returns:
>
> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.`

Are you sure the file path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

As `File.length()` pretty much simply calls into the OS, such difference should not happen. There are several possible reasons (from the most obvious to the more obscure):

- are you actually reading the same file (print the absolute path and use that on the command line)
- have you verified that the file is a "normal" file? I.e. not a device node/symlink/...?
- have you verified that the file is not a sparse file (i.e. the reported size is smaller than the content)? The actually posted content makes this unlikely, however.
- is the JVM running with the same mount points or in a chroot environment?